# How to count files modified this week?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to count files in a directory with a date modified of this current week beginning Monday 12:00:01AM through Sunday.  I want the script to "reset" on Monday at 12:00:01 AM.  I've scrapped the below example a few times in an effort to write my own but this one seems like a good start.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$dow = "Monday"
$today = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek
$FolderResults = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Filter *.* |
    Where-Object {
        $_.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek -eq $dow -AND $_.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek -eq $today
    }).Count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DayOfWeek is an enum (Sunday=0, Monday=1, etc.)

You can leverage that to calculate last Monday's date:

```
$LastMonday = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-(6 + (get-date).DayOfWeek) % 7)).date
```

Then:

```
$FolderResults = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Filter *.* |
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $LastMonday }).Count
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition

```
$_.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek -eq $dow -AND $_.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek -eq $today
```

will give you only the files that were modified on Monday, and only if it actually *is* Monday.

You can use the numeric value of the `DayOfWeek` property for calculating the time frame.

```
$today   = (Get-Date).Date                     # current date, 0:00:00
$offset  = ($today.DayOfWeek.value__ + 6) % 7  # number of days since Monday
$refdate = $today.AddDays(-$offset)            # most recent Monday, 0:00:00

$num = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp' -Filter *.* |
       Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $refdate } |
       Measure-Object |
       Select-Object -Expand Count
```

Comment: +1 Was going to suggest code with Do / Until for checking when it gets to monday but this is much cleaner, i saw value__ on Get-Member but i didnt think i could use it like that..